# On Determinant modulo $2^k$ complexity

Tags: complexity-classes, determinant

Determinant of integer matrix modulo $2$ is complete for the class $\oplus L$. Is determinant modulo $2^k$ computable in $\oplus L$ at any fixed $k$?

How about if $k=o(n)$ where matrix is $n\times n$?

Comment: Have you looked at Valiant's algorithm?

Comment: Actually I think it provides $n^{O(k)}$ algorithm but no I am not familiar in the workings of it.

Comment: Theorem 1 in https://newtraell.cs.uchicago.edu/files/phd_paper/raghav.pdf provides $\oplus L$-completeness for $k=O(1)$.

Comment: Nice find - I can't believe I forgot about that result, now that I see it I recall him telling me about it in person! It'd be worth updating the question. Also, to your second part about growing k, why this question? Would you be interested in fixed-parameter complexity?

Comment: How $\oplus L$ interpolates to $\mathsf{NC}^2$ and how it deviates from $PP$ as $k=\Omega(n)$?